# DNS Setup Failed

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008

My friend wants to set up a new server based on Windows Server 2008.

He installed and configured all needed components like DNS, Mail Server, FTP, IIS, etc.
Now he can access the server's root directory via its IP address; but he wants to have a global access to it via <strike>http</strike> its domain name, `safar724.ir`. Its name server (NS) is `ns1.safar724.ir`.

When we try to ping `ns1.safar724.ir`, the result is not good.

```
[saeed@localhost]~/robots% ping ns1.safar724.ir
ping: unknown host ns1.safar724.ir
```

How can we solve this problem and make our NS global and valid for Domains provider or ISPs?

Answer (score 1):

According to these queries he probably hasn't setup the domain name at the authoritive name servers for that domain:

```
C:\Users\plenderj>nslookup
Default Server:  ie-dub01a-dns01.upc.ie
Address:  89.101.160.4

> set q=ns
> safar724.ir
Server:  ie-dub01a-dns01.upc.ie
Address:  89.101.160.4

Non-authoritative answer:
safar724.ir     nameserver = ikjot.ekkum.com
safar724.ir     nameserver = ikdev.ekkum.com
safar724.ir     nameserver = ns1.ekkum.com
safar724.ir     nameserver = iknoor.ekkum.com
safar724.ir     nameserver = ikdesh.ekkum.com

ikdesh.ekkum.com        internet address = 199.26.68.157
ns1.ekkum.com   internet address = 199.26.68.2
iknoor.ekkum.com        internet address = 24.114.243.251
ikdev.ekkum.com internet address = 64.72.239.182
ikjot.ekkum.com internet address = 208.124.160.124
> set q=a
> ns1.safar724.ir
Server:  ie-dub01a-dns01.upc.ie
Address:  89.101.160.4

*** ie-dub01a-dns01.upc.ie can't find ns1.safar724.ir: Non-existent domain
>
```

He'd probably need to manage his domain on ekkum.com

Comment: thanks, actually we want to change/update name servers which handle .ir domains at this time.

there is more domains like safar724.net/.com but trouble is why our domain provider don't let us to update name servers.

this provider is not ekkum.com.

Comment: Great- I never knew about the nslookup tool under windows.. very nice.. I did use mx toolbox though

Comment: @Saeed; according to nslookup the provider for safar724.ir **is** in fact ekkum.com